# Gnuplot arrowstyle not found

Tags: vector, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a series of vectors with alternating arrow styles in Gnuplot. The 7th column of my data file gnuCors.txt simply alternates between 1 and 2 for each line. Unfortunately when I run this, all of my arrows look the same and I get the warnings:

```
warning: arrowstyle 1 not found
warning: arrowstyle 2 not found
```

I have the following code

```
set xrange [0:4]
set yrange [0:4]

plot "gnuCors.txt" using 1:2:3:4:7 with vectors arrowstyle variable,\
    "" u 5:6:(sprintf("%d", int($0)/2 + 1)) with labels left offset 0.5 
pause -1
```

I haven't seen this error mentioned very frequently on SE. I also looked through the gnuplot documentation on arrow stlyes. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

My graph consists of pairs of vectors. Each pair should have two vector styles so people can distinguish between the two. The coordinates for both of the vectors labeled 1 are in rows 1 and 2 of gnuCors.txt.

"[image]

Comment: Does it make a difference what output format you use?

Comment: I need to use one arrow style for even numbered vectors and another style for odd numbered vectors.

Comment: You must first define the arrow styles you want to use with `set style arrow ...`

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define your arrow styles before you can use any. There are no default arrows styles:

```
set style arrow 1 lt 1 head filled size screen 0.03,15,45
set style arrow 2 lt 2 head empty size screen 0.03,15,135
```

As showcase:

```
set style arrow 1 lt 1 head filled size screen 0.03,15,45
set style arrow 2 lt 2 head empty size screen 0.03,15,135

set xrange [0:10]
set samples 10
plot '+' using 1:1:(1):(0):(int($0)%2 == 0 ? 3 : 6) with vectors arrowstyle variable t ''
```

[image]